# VBA Throwing Mismatch Error With Variables

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting the "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" error on the following line in my code:

```
Cells(i, "E").Value = .WorksheetFunction.Ceiling_Precise(Cells(i, "D").Value * Cells(1, "B").Value, 1)
```

I've been staring at it and can't seem to see what's causing the error. Thanks in advance.

My variables are:

```
Dim i As Long, lRow As Long, subTotal As Long, percentageSum As Double, allFilled As Boolean, c As Integer
```

I tried changing `i` to `Range` and `Integer` but that didn't work.

**Edit - Here's more of the code:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Call calculatePercentage
End Sub

Sub calculatePercentage()
  Dim i As Long, lRow As Long, subTotal As Long, percentageSum As Double, allFilled As Boolean, c As Integer
  lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
  allFilled = True
  For i = 2 To lRow
    If Cells(i, "D").Value = "" And InStr(Cells(i, "C").Value, "Total") = 0 Then
      allFilled = False
    End If
  Next
  If allFilled Then
    With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
  
  
    Range("E2:E" & lRow).Clear
    For i = 2 To lRow
      If InStr(Cells(i, "C").Value, "Total") > 0 Then
        Cells(i, "D").Clear
      End If
    Next
    For i = 2 To lRow + 1
      If i > lRow And Not InStr(Cells(i, "C").Value, "Total") > 0 Then
        Exit For
      End If
      Cells(i, "E").Value = .WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(Cells(i, "D").Value * Cells(1, "B").Value, 1)
      percentageSum = percentageSum + Cells(i, "D").Value
      subTotal = subTotal + Cells(i, "E").Value
      If Cells(i, "D").Value = "" Then
        Cells(i, "D").Value = percentageSum
        Cells(i, "D").NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        Cells(i, "E").Value = subTotal
        If Not c > 0 Then
          percentageSum = 0
          subTotal = 0
          c = c + 1
        End If
      End If
    Next
    .EnableEvents = True
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

**Edit 2:**

[Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erd9d.png)

I need to do the following:

1. Sum up the percentage of each range and put it in the Total column.
2. Take the percentage in each row:

- Multiply it by the Total number cell in the top left corner
- Round it to 0 decimal places
- Put the result in their respective row in the Value column.

3. Once that's done for the Total 1 row, the formula needs reset and do the same for Total 2, and Total 3.
4. It needs to be dynamic so that if a user insert or delete rows, that will be accounted for.

---

- The multiplication would be 5,625,000 (B1) x 14.25% (D3) = 801,563, then 5,625,000 (B1) x 3.00% (D4) = 168,750, and so on...
- The subtotals in Step 1 should be in the Value column. So 801,563 would be in E3, then 168,750 would be in E4 and so on.
- The Percent & Value total of Total 1 subtotals needs to always be in the cell below the very last value in the range in their respective column (in this case: D20 & E20)
- The Percent & Value total of Total 2 subtotals needs to always be in the cell below the very last value in the range in their respective column (in this case: D27 & E27)
- The Percent total of Total 3 is the total of Total 2 (in this case: D27) + the subtotals of Total 3 (in this case: D27:D31) and needs to always be in the cell below the very last value in the range of Total 3 in their respective columns (in this case D32).
- The Value total of Total 3 is the total of Total 2 (in this case: E27) + the subtotals of Total 3 (in this case: E27:E31) and needs to always be in the cell below the very last value in the range of Total 3 in their respective columns (in this case E32).
  -Lastly, all this needs to be dynamic so that it'll take into account when the user adds or deletes a row.

Comment: What are the values in the relevant cells? Add `Debug.Print i, Cells(i, "D").Value , Cells(1, "B").Value` before error line.

Comment: The `i` is suggesting the line is in a loop. What kind of loop? `.WorksheetFunction...` would suggest the line is wrapped in `With Application... End With`. The cells aren't qualified, so they are located on the active sheet. Are you sure the active sheet is the correct one? Please share more code and a screenshot of your worksheet.

Comment: Hi y'all, thank you for the replies. I edited the post to include more code.

Comment: Did you add the `Debug.Print` statement ? If so what was the result in the Immediate window

Comment: It says "True" in the Immediate window.

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Sub calculatePercentage(ws As Worksheet)

    Dim lastrow As Long, r0 As Long
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, f As String

    On Error GoTo MyErrHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        r0 = 3
        For i = r0 To lastrow
            
            If LCase(.Cells(i, "C")) Like "total*" Then
                n = r0 - i
                f = "=Round(Sum(R[" & n & "]C:R[-1]C),0)"
                .Cells(i, "D").FormulaR1C1 = f
                r0 = i + 1
            End If
            ' value
            f = "=ROUND(R1C2 * RC[-1],0)"
            .Cells(i, "E").FormulaR1C1 = f
            
        Next
    End With
    
MyErrHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run various permutations of possibilities, produced several different error messages, and more importantly I have reproduced your error message.

You are getting the error message because your i variable is defined as a letter, word or some other non-numeric character.  You need to look through your code and find where the i value is set, or where the value is changed, and you will find the error that needs to be corrected.

Either that, or you have a string or boolean value in one of your spreadsheet cells in the B or D columns; check that your start and end values for your i are correct, for example check you are not trying to multiply column headers.  I note that the second value being multiplied is Cells(1, "B"), row 1 column B, perhaps that should have been * Cells(i, "B").

Comment: Hi, I edited the post to include more code. Thank you.